# wget or curl file containing string of 8 random integers

Tags: curl, wildcard, wget

I want to download a podcast daily. It takes the form of an mp3 file, so the extension of the target file is always the same. The first part of the file's name also does not change--let's call it ProgName-. Another segment of the file name changes in predictable ways; it is today's date, in the form 01-01-1999. But the middle part of the file's name changes in fairly unpredictable ways: it consists in a string of 8 apparently random integers. The ending of the file name, i.e., the part prior to the extension, also does not change--let's say it's "-full." So a sample file name for the 1st of January 1999 would look as follows: ProgName-01-01-1999-01238764-full.mp3. The file for the next day, January 2nd, would be named ProgName-01-02-1999-23871640-full.mp3. And so forth.

The files are made available through http, and I can download them using wget once I've discovered the full path by browsing to the web page. But I'm trying to automate this and am hoping to come up with a cron job I can run at a certain hour each day, at a time when I'm certain the latest episode will be available. As an example

`wget http://my.desiredurl.here/downloads/ProgName-01-01-1999-01238764-full.mp3`

successfully downloads the file ProgName-01-01-199-01238764-full.mp3 to my computer (non-credentialed site). But until I can come up with a way (perhaps by using wildcards or brace expansion?) to automate this, I am stuck downloading manually. So I'd like to ask for help.

I've done some reading on brace expansion but am at a sufficiently rudimentary level with bash that I'm kind of guessing how this might work. Could I expect

`wget http://my.desiredurl.here/downloads/ProgName-01-01-1999-{00000000..99999999}-full.mp3`

to work? Is that even the optimal way to do this sort of thing? I think I've puzzled out how to automate the entry of the date part of the file name, but am currently stumped regarding the integer string. Input will be appreciated.

PS I did a fair amount of googling about this issue before posting here. Most of the wget solutions I ran across involved globbing and recursive downloading, which really is not what I need. There are a number of .mp3 files at the target site, but I only need one of them. I need a way of filtering out all but the target file containing today's date. curl is also on my machine and could be used for this, though my focus has been on wget, with which I'm more familiar.

Comment: scrape html page, extract url (parse html with a DOM tool), download url, ???, profit

Comment: You absolutely, positively don't want to send 100,000,000 requests (which is what your brace expansion would do if it worked, which it won't for reasons related to ARG_MAX and the like). You won't finish within a day, *and* the folks running the server will notice and ban you.

Comment: ...so, what you need to do is find the actual URL. It's going to be published somewhere. And, err, wget has *really good* tools for filtering when doing a recursive download, so there's nothing hard or at all nonobvious about filtering for the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a resolution to this issue. A bit more convoluted than I'd envisioned, but tests so far indicate it should do the job. I was aided in coming to a resolution by 1) realization that with either curl or wget I could download an xml document that contains (among others) the direct link I need; and 2) running across instructions, some of which I have reappropiated, for doing something that bears at least some similarities to my task, at http://nylinuxhelp.com/blogs/command-line/download-several-files-part-2.

First, I use curl to grab the xml file that contains the needed URL. I pipe that as output to grep, telling it to search for a string that begins with http and ends with mp3, and to end that search after finding the first result; -m 1, which happens to be the most recent episode that I am targeting. Finally, the output of that grep command gets piped, via xargs, to wget, which downloads, then renames the file. The full one-liner looks like this:

`curl http://my.desiredurl.here/level1/level2/ | grep -m 1 -o "http:.*mp3" | xargs -n1 wget -O MyDownloaded.mp3`

I need to do further testing to ensure it will work as desired when set up as a cron job. I can probably remove -n1 from the xargs segment of this routine, since I should only ever be feeding from xargs one URL to wget at a time. I should embed this into a primitive bash script as well, since I'd like to incorporate the date into the file name after the fashion demonstrated by Charles above.

LATER EDIT: I've run a test this evening with this script set up as a cron job and it performed like a champ. Of course it's quite primitive and has no error checking, logging, or redirecting of extraneous output. So it certainly could use improvement. My bash "skills," such as they are, don't permit me to do much more than I already have, so I'll make due with it as-is for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Tell wget to filter for your expected filename pattern, and hand it a URL from which you expect a download link to be available.

This would look something like:

```
date=$(date +%m-%d-%Y) # aside: Awful date format; %Y-%m-%d is what sane folks use.
expected_name="ProgName-$date-*.mp3"

wget --recursive --level=2 --accept "$expected_name" http://my.desiredurl.here/
```

Note the `--level=2` -- this limits the depth of recursion. Modify to the minimum value necessary relative to the URL provided (and try to make that URL as close to the location of the download link as possible).

Comment: This is an appealing solution and one I more or less understand. I made a bash script out of it but so far it's not working (it downloads, not an mp3 file, but something that looks like and index.html). The real URL is closer to http://my.desiredurl.here/level1/level2/, btw. So I chose --level-3. I also did added "full" to expected_name="ProgName-$date-*-full.mp3" Thanks for the contribution which looks like it should work. Now trying to diagnose why it doesn't perform as expected.

Comment: Think I understand where the problem lies. The URL I'm using actually has an xml file that acts as a kind of index page, and the links I'm after are embedded in that xml file. wget is for some reason retrieving that xml file rather than the file the mp3 file the script specifies. Somehow it works fine when I wget the full URL, file name included. But when the script tries to fetch that file, the xml file gets downloaded instead.

Comment: If you can download the XML file, extracting an explicit list of URLs should be simple -- there are plenty of Q&A entries describing how to use XMLStarlet and similar tools to extract data from XML in bash.